# IntelliJ IDEA's Show History Button Doesn't Show Timestamps and Git Committers and Git Comments

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Am using the following version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition:

```
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.3 Ultimate Edition
Builde #IU-202.7660.26, built on October 6, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 x86_65
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

On macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with the following version of git installed:

```
git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

Whenever, I click on the Show History button located on the top right hand corner:

[image: Show History]

Now, it only shows me a diff of all the changes for that particular file whose is focus set on (file that is active in the editor), but earlier, it used to show me a list of timestamps, git committers (along with git comments).

How do I set IntelliJ IDEA (via Preferences) to show me the git history (timestamp, committers & comments) instead of the open file's diffs?

Comment: Why did my post get a -1 vote? This is after all a very legitimate question that needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have log window hidden at the left side. Could you please locate your mouse on the left border of the History toolwindow and see whether "Resize" cursor appears and if so, please drag it to the right. Then you should be able to see a log of history.

Comment: Sorry, it still only shows the diffs but not the author name, timestamp & git comment... When I click on Log tab, it's completely empty.

Comment: Please check the border of your window - there could be a resize cursor available. If you see only Log (graph), but files, committer info etc is not there - please check the right side of a window, looks like it's hidden and you need to drag it to the left. It would help if you share a screenshot of what you see.